# Testing Marionette Router in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, marionette

I'd like to test that my app routes have meaning in the connected controller.  [Testing Marionette Modules in isolation with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789988/testing-marionette-modules-in-isolation-with-jasmine) Looked like it might work for me, but it didn't. (the spy isn't called, instead the controller function itself is called)
this is what I've got so far
Test:

```
it('navigates to showItem', function (){
  var instance = new PmsRouter();
  spyOn(instance.controller, "showItem");
  Backbone.history.start();
  instance.navigate("system/pms/1", {trigger:true});
  expect(instance.controller.showItem).toHaveBeenCalledWith("1");
  window.location.hash = ""
});
```

Modules:

```
'use strict';


define([
  'underscore',
  'modules/admin/system/pms/PmsController',
  'marionette'

], function(_ ,PmsController) {

  var PmsRouter = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
    controller: new PmsController(),
    appRoutes: {
      'system/pms/:pms_id': 'showItem'
    }
  });

  return PmsRouter;
});
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What about spying on `PmsRouter.prototype.showItem`?

Comment: Thanks! that ill work